# fortran77: arrays of pointers or arrays of structures?

Tags: arrays, pointers, fortran77

I'm trying to optimize a code in fortran77 and I'd like to know whether the arrays declared in the following way inside a routine or an header file are arrays of pointers or arrays of structures:

case 1: real*8 xred(maxatm)

case 2: common /atoms/ x(maxatm)

I've already searched over the internet but I couldn't find any info on this, the only thing I found was that when you pass an array to a routine it is passed by reference. But regarding when it is declared in header file or inside the routine I found nothing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand your question. First off, standard fortran 77 has no concept of header files, so please explain what exactly you mean by them. Neither does f77 have pointers or structures. Regarding what you found on passing by reference: the standard says nothing at all about it, so even though it is probably the most common way, it is still implementation dependent.

Comment: He is just asking what goes on 'under-the-hood'. Header files in F77 are include/COMMON (.CMN etc.) files they play basically the same role as .h headers in C (although implemented slightly differently). F77 does have `POINTER`s in the framework. From the spec: "Each pointer contains the address of its paired variable.
A pointer-based variable is a variable paired with a pointer in a POINTER statement. A pointer-based variable is usually called just a based variable. The pointer is the integer variable that contains the address."

Comment: Moreover, I think what is meant in the question by structure and pointer is what is done by the F77 compiler to manage memory. The standard is clear, all values passed to `SUBROUTINE`s and `FUNCTION`s are by reference _not_ value. Also, yes there are `STRUCTURE`s in F77 depending on compiler choice.

Comment: @Killercam: If that's what's being asked, it should be in the question. I know about the `include` statement, but the wording of the question suggests that variables are declared inside 'header files', while in fact it's nothing more than textual replacement before compilation proper takes place, so any declaration is actually inside a regular program unit. The text you quote on pointers is not from the f77 standard, and nowhere does the standard explicitly mention pass by reference or value. Since this is all implementation specific, the question should specify which compiler is being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a .f77 'header'/common/.CMN file you are declaring your variables to be used within your program. The space required for these variables is established at compile time for each file that contains the header declaration. So for 'My.CMN' which contains

```
REAL*8 XEDG(-2:MAXNB+4)  ! left x-edges of cells    
REAL*8 YEDG(-2:MAXNB+4)  ! left y-edges of cells 
REAL*8 XC(-2:MAXNB+4) ! X CELL CENTERS
REAL*8 YC(-2:MAXNB+4) ! Y CELL CENTERS
```

These variables are created each time they are declared in a .f77 file via `INCLUDE 'My.CMN'`.

However, using a common block

```
COMMON /GRID/ XEDG,YEDG,XC,YC
```

tells the compiler that the variables contained within a given .CMN file (or whatever) are to some extend global/shared, here the compiler will use pointers to the relevent space in memory.

```
The COMMON statement defines a block of main memory storage so that 
different program units can share the same data without using arguments.
```

See [here](http://www.obliquity.com/computer/fortran/common.html) for more information on `COMMON` and [here](http://wwwcdf.pd.infn.it/localdoc/f77_sun.pdf) for the Sun FORTRAN 77 4.0 Compiler Reference Manual.